# Can’t find the “app.js” file when attempting to work on a project with React Native

Tags: sublime-text-3, node.js

I am trying to start working in React Native.

After having the device connected by the expo app, it says in the “[Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)” site:

> “Now that you have successfully run the app, let’s modify it. Open App.js in your text editor of choice and edit some lines.”

I downloaded Sublime Text 3, but I don’t see there any app.js file.

Is that a file that i should create somewhere or is it suppose to be in the code editor? How do I get it connected with React Native?

Comment: Got it! oppened!

Comment: i get an error: Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: No Android device found

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/490).

Comment: If you found my advice to be helpful, please be sure to upvote [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1422983/167207). If [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1422983/167207) is the answer that helped solve your issue, please be sure to check it off as such.

Answer (score 0):

Checking [the tutorial you mention](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) it states this command should be run:

```
expo init AwesomeProject
```

If so, then I believe that `app.js` file should be in that directory. Just open it up like any other file and you should be good to go!